# SLIME who-calls errors out with 'nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth'

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, spacemacs

Using Spacemacs 0.105, all packages updated.

Using *Slime's* `who-calls` on a symbol errors out with `nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth`.

I've tried setting the eval-depth with

```cl
(setq max-lisp-eval-depth 10000)
```

That then gives me this error: `Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`

So then I tried setting that as well

```cl
(setq max-specpdl-size 32000)
```

Which then gives me the eval-depth error again, so it's just going round in circles.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an error, setting max-lisp-eval-depth won't help. You need to find and fix the error. Let's say there is an infinite recursion, setting the eval depth to infinity still won't help.

Comment: I've tried running `who-calls` on numerous other code bases, not just mine, the error is still there. I even tried `(defun fun-1 () (fun-2)) (defun fun-2 () '1)` and ran `who-calls` on `fun-2`, it just errors out.

Comment: So this seems to be related to Spacemacs, since running my old init file makes the command work. I'll bring it up with them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with my emacs with slime

the functions code as you suggested is:

```
(defun fun-1 () (fun-2)) 

(defun fun-2 () '1)
```

then put the cursor after each functions and press C-x C-e

with that you evaluate this expressions

Then the function that you're looking for is slime-who-calls

M-x slime-who-calls [ret]

type fun-2

it will open a new buffer with this

```
(No location)
  FUN-1
```

adding a capture

[image]